# How to deploy nestjs into cloud run use mutiple env

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, nestjs, google-cloud-run

I use **nestjs** and **docker** deploy into cloud run. My project have multiple env : **.env.dev (develop) , .env.stg(staging) and .env.prod(prouct)**. Now i want when i deploy into staging i use .env.stg because it contain all information env stg.Same with dev and prod. But i don't know how to put .env.stg into my Dockerfile. Docker file look like :

```
###################
# BUILD FOR LOCAL DEVELOPMENT
###################

FROM node:18-alpine As development

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# A wildcard is used to ensure copying both package.json AND package-lock.json (when available).
# Copying this first prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies using the `npm ci` command instead of `npm install`
RUN npm ci

# Bundle app source
COPY --chown=node:node . .

# Use the node user from the image (instead of the root user)
USER node

###################
# BUILD FOR PRODUCTION
###################

FROM node:18-alpine As build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

# In order to run `npm run build` we need access to the Nest CLI which is a dev dependency. In the previous development stage we ran `npm ci` which installed all dependencies, so we can copy over the node_modules directory from the development image
COPY --chown=node:node --from=development /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules

COPY --chown=node:node . .

# Run the build command which creates the production bundle
RUN npm run build

# Set NODE_ENV environment variable
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Running `npm ci` removes the existing node_modules directory and passing in --only=production ensures that only the production dependencies are installed. This ensures that the node_modules directory is as optimized as possible
RUN npm ci --only=production && npm cache clean --force

USER node

###################
# PRODUCTION
###################

FROM node:18-alpine As production

# Copy the bundled code from the build stage to the production image
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

# Start the server using the production build
CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js" ]
```

How to deploy nestjs with specific env with difference environment

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy NestJS into Cloud Run using multiple environments, check the following steps:

1. Create a separate Dockerfile for each environment. For example, you could create a `Dockerfile.dev`, `Dockerfile.stg`, and `Dockerfile.prod`.
2. In each Dockerfile, add a `COPY` instruction to copy the appropriate .env file into the container. For example, in the `Dockerfile.stg`, you would add the following `COPY` instruction:

```
COPY .env.stg .env
```

3. When you build the Docker image for each environment, specify the appropriate .env file using the `-e` flag. For example, to build the staging image, you would run the following command:

```
docker build -t my-app:stg -e ENV=stg
```

4. When you deploy the Docker image to Cloud Run, specify the environment name using the `-e ENV=stg` flag. For example, to deploy the staging image, you would run the following command:

```
gcloud run deploy my-app --image my-app:stg -e ENV=stg
```

Here is an example of a staging environment:

```
FROM node:18-alpine

# Copy the .env.stg file into the container
COPY .env.stg .env

# Install the application dependencies
RUN npm ci

# Run the NestJS application
CMD ["node", "dist/main.js"]
```